# Mapping proper type for interface property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have the following interface type in a module ( module1 ) which I'm developing.

```ts
interface ModuleOneInterface {
    keyOne: customInterface;
    keyTwo: customInterface;
    keyThree: customInterface;
}
```

So I'm currently developing a second module ( module2 ) which uses the above interface as a prop in its component. The above interface is not exported from the module ( module1 ) hence I can't import it ( module2 ). I declared another interface which could represent the type in my second module ( module2 ). Below is the interface.

```ts
export interface ModuleTwoInterface {
    //This is the one which is accepting module one interface
    module2KeyOne: Record<string, customInterface>; 
    module2KeyTwo: string;
}
```

But this throws the following error.

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'ModuleOneInterface' is not assignable to parameter 
        of type 'Record<string, customInterface>'.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried the following solution as well. But it didn't work as well.

```ts
interface moduleTwoSubInterface {
    [ key: string ]: customInterface;
}

export interface ModuleTwoInterface {
    // This is the one which is accepting module one interface
    module2KeyOne: moduleTwoSubInterface; 
    module2KeyTwo: string;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?

Comment: If `ModuleOneInterface` is already being used by another external module, that would seem like a very good incentive to export it, no? It is rare for packages to omit types, usually even private/internal ones, because the whole point of the type system is to make developing with your module easier.

Answer (score 0):

`type` and `interface` are interchangeable *most* of the time, but not always.

An interface without an index signature does not extend anything with an index signature, and therefore is not assignable to it.
A type alias on the other hand does extend any target type (using `type` or `interface`) that has an index signature, if and only if all of its properties comply with the index signature. IE. If the index signature is from `string` to `Foo`, all of its properties must be able to extend `Foo`.

Here is a minimal example on the playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhNdlaJQbwChkSBnAewFsIAKASgC5lSwpQBzAbkIF9DDQOeEjQAxcuWRESyGBKbpMUbNGEQANL35gAngAcUAFXGSAvFOIk55BRizhVeTT26FdB5IbhR2EMMnMAJQgEcigAEwAeFjYQdnU0O2UHXCQAPldQkBZkYACpHmQ4UjEJbiyc-3N8QuLPE1cYAFcQBDBgchBkMDgAawhSAFEAD0hsjpAAeRhDSMDkCFGIEHCSrx8-NJoAfSgmQMZkADdyYHCC7T6BkbHSCenDGmA6bh7+oaXxzoeaMBf+AD0AOQAEFSHd2CAON1JOtfGB+BV-DAoFRUEw4X58sByp0ciiqIYMd54fkwJwgA)